# Could not extract link from a div class using html agility xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I am new to html agility, I tried to get a mp3 link in the source code below:

```
<div id="fullPlayer">
               <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stc.m.nixcdn.com/js/html5-player.0.1.js"></script>
        <div class="player">
            <div class="hide-html5">
                <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
                    <source src="http://aredir.nixcdn.com/18c5db02a7804db01de320c1d34e5e6d/582c6bb4/NhacCuaTui217/Anh-HoQuynhHuong_3ycwf.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                </audio>
            </div> 
            <div id="play" class="play control">
            </div>
```

When I tried, I could not access the "hide-html5" node, but it is ok for the "fullPlayer". Thus, the src attribute is not for image , in this case, it is an audio link. Looking at the structure, the "hide-html5" node is the child node of "fullPlayer", then how could I extract the mp3 link from it? 
Below is the code I used but failed.

```
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load("http://m.nhaccuatui.com/bai-hat/anh-ho-quynh-huong.hp7uaRRC5ID1.html")
Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='hide-html5']")
If Not div Is Nothing Then
      Dim att As HtmlAttribute = div.Attributes("src")
      MsgBox(att.Value)
Else
      Msgbox("not accessible")
End if
```

Does it need any special code to access the child node in html agility?, Please share. Thank you ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to get the `src` attribute of a `div` but he doesn't have one as I see, you need to get the `src` attribute of the source element.

The selector for the source could be one of the following:

```
//div[@id='fullPlayer']//source
//audio[@id='audio']//source
```

Finding this node and getting his `src` attribute should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got more confused after reading it. Perhaps I gotta learn more on Xpath and come back with the problem. : )